# WebStorm 2018.1.4 + ESLint: TypeError: this.CliEngine is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, eslint, webstorm

My configuration is this.

WebStorm 2018.1.4; ESLint 6.4;  Node 12.8; npm 6.10.2; Windows 8.1.

How do I eliminate the error in the thread title?

Here's a code sample.

```
import {
  GET_DAILY_SUCCESS,
  GET_HOURLY_SUCCESS,
  GET_MINUTE_SUCCESS
} from './types';
import {
  getDailyToUsd,
  getHourlyToUsd,
  getMinuteToUsd
} from '../api/cryptocompare';
import { setError } from './error';

export const getDaily = (fsym = 'BTC') => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const list = await getDailyToUsd(fsym);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_DAILY_SUCCESS,
      currency: fsym,
      list
    });
  } catch(err) {
    dispatch(setError(err.Message));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

[WEB-38922](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38922) is fixed in 2019.1.3.
The issue is with ESLint version 6.x.  If upgrading Webstorm is not an option for you, you have to downgrade to ESLint version 5:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint@5
```

Update: if you see similar error when working with ESLint 8, please make sure to upgrade to version 2021.2.2 where it's supported (see [WEB-52236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52236))

Comment: worked for me (updated up to 2021.2.2). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! No errors in Webstorm 2021.2.3

Comment: Now Eslint 7 works btw.

Comment: How do you find the the right version from 2021.2.2
They don't show dates on npm.

Answer (score 35):

In my Webstorm 2021.2 there is a slightly different error `this.CliEngineCtor is not a constructor`.

That is related to updating eslint to 8.0.1.

Solution: update WebStorm to the latest version 2021.2.2 or later

Answer (score 25):

Here is another [solution from Dmitry Babenko](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38922) that will let you use ESLint 6.x with a fallback license of WebStorm:

> - Wait for the `this.CliEngine is not a constructor` balloon to appear and click "Details"
> - Follow the first link in the stack-trace to `eslint-plugin.js` file
> - Find the following line at the top:
>   `this.CliEngine = require(this.basicPath + "lib/cli-engine");`
>   And replace it with the following one:
>   `this.CliEngine = require(this.basicPath).CLIEngine;`
> - Restart IDEA

Comment: Mine looks like this...

this.cliEngineCtor = requireInContext(eslintPackagePath + "lib/api", state.packageJsonPath).CLIEngine;

Answer (score 25):

In additional to **Dabrule** answer:

For eslint v8 replace this line:

```
this.cliEngineCtor = requireInContext(eslintPackagePath + "lib/api", state.packageJsonPath).CLIEngine;
```

to that:

```
this.cliEngineCtor = requireInContext(eslintPackagePath + "lib/cli-engine").CLIEngine;
```

File location, for example, RubyMine (WebStorm should be similar):

`RubyMine-2021.1.3/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/languageService/eslint/bin/eslint-plugin.js`

Comment: Worked for me: RubyMine-2021.1.3. The best thing, no need to downgrade ESLint, nor to upgrade RubyMine / WebStorm.

Comment: Worked for me. PyCharm + eslint 8

Comment: Works on: IDEA 2020.3.4 + eslint 8.19.0

Comment: worked on webstorm 2021.2 and eslint 8.21. Thanks

Comment: worked on pycharm 2021.1.2

Comment: works for Intellij Idea 2021.1.3 and eslint 8.22.0 but I got another error "Error while loading rule 'jest/no-deprecated-functions'" :D

Answer (score 23):

I'm using Webstorm2021.2.1 and I have figured out that eslint@8.0.0 is not compatible with it.
This worked for me:

```
yarn add -D eslint@7.14.0
```

Answer (score 2):

upgrading to newer version will solve this error.

As you can see the issue was solved in 2019.1.3

*WEB-38922 - Linting with ESLint v6 in 2019.1 fails with an error 'TypeError: this.cliEngine is not a constructor'* : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38922

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In additional to Dabrule and Johny Martin answer:

For eslint 8+ add .CLIEngine to this line:

```
this.CliEngine = require(this.basicPath + "lib/cli-engine").CLIEngine
```

Restart IDE (Webstorm 2018.1.2)