# WebStorm 2020 ESLint: TypeError: this.CliEngine is not a constructor

Tags: eslint, webstorm

My configuration is WebStorm 2020.2.3, ESLint 8.11.0, Node.js v16.14.2.

Getting the `ESLint: TypeError: this.CliEngine is not a constructor` error while opening .js files:
[image]

Searching for `WebStorm ESLint: TypeError: this.CliEngine is not a constructor` on Google and StackOverflow, and going through answers people give, such as manually editing lines in Webstorm did not help me to solve this issue on this version of WebStorm - 2020.2.3.

This question is not a duplicate of [WebStorm 2018.1.4 + ESLint: TypeError: this.CliEngine is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944468/webstorm-2018-1-4-eslint-typeerror-this-cliengine-is-not-a-constructor). Different version of the IDE and the bug is different in a different place, the code in the file is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESLint 8 is supported since 2021.2.2, see [WEB-52236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52236); please consider updating the IDE

Comment: Thanks, that should probably work. I'm always hesitant to update programs nowadays, for many years now. Because updates tend to introduce bugs to features I can't live without. And then I want to go back but can't find that version of the program from a year or two before.

Comment: @KulaGGin *"And then I want to go back but can't find that version of the program from a year or two before."* You can find ALL previous versions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/other.html (that's for WebStorm). For any JetBrains product: you just go to the product page, go to the "Download" page for that product and then click on "Other versions" link there.

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to solve this issue on WebStorm 2020 without updating to a newer version:

- Install older than 8.0.0 version of eslint anywhere on your machine
  using any method you like. I installed version 7.32.0 globally with
  npm: `npm install -g eslint@7.32.0`.
- Go to Settings > Languages &
  Frameworks > JavaScript > Code and Quality Tools > ESLint. Select
  `Manual ESLint Configuration` and select the version older than 8.0.0:

[image]